# Django Template Image not displaying even with media url and media root

Tags: django, image, django-templates, django-settings

Static images are showing properly. The files in the media folder are not displaying in `html`. I tried setting up media_url in various ways but in vain. I uploaded the image via django admin panel. The name of product is showing fine. The img.url shows ***/media/p2.jpg***

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = CharField(("Name"),max_length=256,blank=False)
    title_img = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

settings.py

```
PROJECT_ROOT = (os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT  =   os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(PROJECT_ROOT), "media_root")
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('', ProductList.as_view() , name="product"),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

template.html

```
{{p.name}}
<img src="{{p.title_img.url}}">
```

the name is displayed while image is not displayed.  In console, I get

```
"GET /media/p2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2690
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed some settings and was able to resolve it. Probably the mistake was that I was changing `project_root/products/urls.py` instead or `project_root/urls.py`. Overall changes I did:

In main urls.py, added these

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('', ProductList.as_view() , name="product"),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Changed `settings.py`

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

1. it should be used only for development purposes,
2. settings.DEBUG must be set to True,
3. it works only if the url is local

in your case, 1 and 3 seams ok but is your DEBUG setting set to True?

As per the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#runserver, you can runserver with argument --insecure so you can still serve static files or media file with DEBUG set to False.

Comment: debug is set to true